# Objective C parse JSON

Tags: ios, asp.net, objective-c, json, wcf

I Have this result JSON below that i get from my wcf service which i want to iterate through in my ipad app.I use the code below to parse the result json but the app gives error. How can iterate through this dictionary and get the items.

IOS Code:

```
   myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSString* URL = @"http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/ListTopReports";
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [JSONHelper loadJSONDataFromURL:URL ];
        NSString *result=[dictionary valueForKey:@"ListTopReportsResult"];
        NSLog(@"%@",result);

   /* for (NSString* key in result ) {

        id value=[result objectForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"%@ -+",value);

    }
   */
```

JSON:

```
{
ListTopReportsResult: [
{
AppUserID: null,
Author: "Joe Matthew",
Company: "Coca-Cola",
Country: "Poland",
CreationDate: "8/20/2014 4:32:00 AM",
EndDate: null,
ResearchReportID: "2",
Sector: "Soft Drinks",
Summary: "da ascon casmld lmasdlasd",
Title: "Can Coca-cola beat the market?",
URL: "2123123.pdf"
},
{
AppUserID: null,
Author: "martina pawlik",
Company: "Cimsa",
Country: "Poland",
CreationDate: "8/20/2014 4:31:00 AM",
EndDate: null,
ResearchReportID: "1",
Sector: "Cement",
Summary: "asd adas asd asdasd asdasdasd",
Title: "Poland's cement sector is on the rise",
URL: "1123123.pdf"
}
]
}
```

Comment: `result` should be a `NSArray`, not a `NSString`.

Comment: this may help you NSArray *yourArray=[dictionary valueForKey:@"yourKey"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *result=[dictionary valueForKey:@"ListTopReportsResult"];
```

Because in your JSON, there is an array for key `ListTopReportsResult`.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this. This is not the exact solution and you'll have to work around your way.

```
NSString *link =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourServiceURL"];
    NSString *encdLink = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:encdLink];
    NSData *response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Now you have your data in the array and extract it out using `objectForKey` or `valueForKey`.You can use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` as per your requirement.

Firstly get the array from the above code. Then extract out the image content like this :

```
_demoArray = [json valueForKey:@"yourKeyField"];
```

Now you have the values in your `demoArray`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the answer of Rashad and it worked, I will also test this and post results but since Stackoverflow accepts only one answer i will save this as helpful. Thanks for your quick reply.